# i want to submit lyrics to lyrics.wikia.com but copyright infringement issues?

Tags: wiki, copyright

i want to submit lyrics to  lyrics.wikia.com but I worry about copyright infringement issues

I do not understand how the Copyrights work in lyrics.wikia.com

They [claimed](http://lyrics.wikia.com/LyricWiki%3aCopyrights) that `Copyrights to lyrics are held by their respective owners and are licensed through Gracenote`.

However how is this possible if the content is user-submitted?

Example, a user (me) submitted copyrighted lyrics to lyrics.wikia.com, then wouldn't lyrics.wikia.com be in trouble?

I've read these links:

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B1sXZG13-t3BZjA0Zjg1ZTctODQzOS00OGUxLWJlMzctYmY1ZGI2ZDJkNGQy&hl=en&pli=1

http://www.aimp.org/education/articles/2/NMPA_Press_Announcement_-_PUBLISHERS_SUCCESSFULLY_RESOLVE_INFRINGEMENT_SUIT

http://privacyandip.blogspot.com/2009/08/new-copyright-suit-filed-against.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lyrics Wikia tries to license all user submitted lyrics content via Gracenote which is a service selling rights to use Song meta data according to their [FAQ](http://lyrics.wikia.com/LyricWiki%3aCopyrights). However I'm unsure whether they are actually doing this and what about songs that aren't in Gracenote's database.

Comment: that's what I'm asking. If there's a new song that just got released last week and i upload the lyrics, chances are it's not already licensed in Gracenote. so basically how do they solve this problem? or can a layman simply do that to bring alot of complains / files upon LyricsWiki?

Comment: @Pacerier: Chances are high that the song is licensed as all major labels are Gracenote partners. But yes, I someone adds many unlicensed songs that could bring the site down. That's the risk.